# How can I build a custom alert message with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get a alert message to the end user with different text on the responses.  Instead of OK/Cancel, I would like to have Continue/Cancel.  Then if they select Continue then go to the function that I created.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Showalert() {
            alert('Are you sure you want to go forward?');               
        }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"
            runat="server"
            Text="Submit"
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click">
```

Or is there a alert in C# that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a button pressed the easy way to hold it and not post back on client side is the `confirm()` dialog of the browser as:

```
<script>
function DoubleCheck()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to go forward?...");
}
</script>
```

and on asp.net part you use the `OnClientClick` to call it client side

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return DoubleCheck();"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```